# How to use variable into differents functions?

Tags: variables, environment-variables, global-variables, autohotkey

I have multiple functions like this :

```
    f1(){
    Run my.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 -param4
}

    f2(){
    Run my.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 -param4
}

    f3(){
    Run my.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 -param4
}
```

I would like to store all those common parameters into a variable to avoid repeating myself.

```
params := "-param1 -param2 -param3 -param4"
    f1(){
    Run my.exe %params%
    }
    f2(){
    Run my.exe %params%
    }
    f3(){
    Run my.exe %params%
    }
```

But it does not work, and I'm not able to figure out why.

I realize the `%params%` can't be read as I see this return a blank message :

```
params := "-param1 -param2 -param3 -param4"
f1(){
MsgBox, %params%
}
```

What should I do to use variable stored common arguments into multiple differents functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the assignment to the `params` variable comes at the top of the script (i.e., the auto-execute section) and add `global params` to the function:

```
params := "-param1 -param2 -param3 -param4"
f1() {
  global params
  MsgBox, %params%
}
```